# Durable subscription ID cannot be read by CSV Data Set Config in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jms, messagebroker, jms-topic, durable-subscription

I need to get 10 different durable subscribers added to a message broker by reading the durable subscription IDs to be set from a csv file which contains integer values from 1 - 10. However, JMeter was failing to read the value instead it tried to set the subscritpition ID as ${id}. Below is the configuration that I have done in JMeter.

[image]

[image]

Please note that when I tried the same by a user defined variable it will then get the value of the variable and create the durable subscription successfully.

JMeter log below.

```
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : DueTopic1 - Node 1- Sub 1 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group DueTopic1 - Node 1- Sub 1. 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: DueTopic1 - Node 1- Sub 1 1-1 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber: Error during close:  javax.jms.JMSException: Error closing connection: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionClosedException: Error: Subscription ID: carbon:${id} cannot contain any of following symbols ~!@#;%^*()+={}|<>"', and space. " / " can only use as the tenant separator
 [error code 541: internal error]
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.doClose(AMQConnection.java:971)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.close(AMQConnection.java:897)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.close(AMQConnection.java:888)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.close(AMQConnection.java:883)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.Utils.close(Utils.java:78)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.close(ReceiveSubscriber.java:359)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.<init>(ReceiveSubscriber.java:255)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.<init>(ReceiveSubscriber.java:115)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.initReceiveClient(SubscriberSampler.java:126)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.threadStarted(SubscriberSampler.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:647)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:616)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:237)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionClosedException: Error: Subscription ID: carbon:${id} cannot contain any of following symbols ~!@#;%^*()+={}|<>"', and space. " / " can only use as the tenant separator
 [error code 541: internal error]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.andes.AMQException.cloneForCurrentThread(AMQException.java:110)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.writeCommandFrameAndWaitForReply(AMQProtocolHandler.java:640)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.syncWrite(AMQProtocolHandler.java:676)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.closeConnection(AMQProtocolHandler.java:707)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.closeConnection(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:61)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.doClose(AMQConnection.java:955)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionClosedException: Error: Subscription ID: carbon:${id} cannot contain any of following symbols ~!@#;%^*()+={}|<>"', and space. " / " can only use as the tenant separator
 [error code 541: internal error]
    at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ConnectionCloseMethodHandler.methodReceived(ConnectionCloseMethodHandler.java:91)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.dispatchConnectionClose(ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.java:192)
    at org.wso2.andes.framing.amqp_0_91.ConnectionCloseBodyImpl.execute(ConnectionCloseBodyImpl.java:140)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.state.AMQStateManager.methodReceived(AMQStateManager.java:111)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.methodBodyReceived(AMQProtocolHandler.java:517)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolSession.methodFrameReceived(AMQProtocolSession.java:467)
    at org.wso2.andes.framing.AMQMethodBodyImpl.handle(AMQMethodBodyImpl.java:96)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler$2.run(AMQProtocolHandler.java:468)
    at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.processAll(Job.java:109)
    at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.run(Job.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more

2016/08/29 17:56:39 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler: Could not initialise client javax.jms.JMSException: Error registering consumer: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionClosedException: Error: Subscription ID: carbon:${id} cannot contain any of following symbols ~!@#;%^*()+={}|<>"', and space. " / " can only use as the tenant separator
 [error code 541: internal error]
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession$6.execute(AMQSession.java:2143)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession$6.execute(AMQSession.java:2086)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.executeRetrySupport(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:324)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$3.run(AMQConnection.java:655)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.executeRetrySupport(AMQConnection.java:652)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.failover.FailoverRetrySupport.execute(FailoverRetrySupport.java:102)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createConsumerImpl(AMQSession.java:2084)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createConsumer(AMQSession.java:1072)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(AMQSession.java:1226)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(AMQSession.java:1121)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.createSubscriber(ReceiveSubscriber.java:284)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.<init>(ReceiveSubscriber.java:239)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.<init>(ReceiveSubscriber.java:115)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.initReceiveClient(SubscriberSampler.java:126)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.threadStarted(SubscriberSampler.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:647)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:616)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:237)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionClosedException: Error: Subscription ID: carbon:${id} cannot contain any of following symbols ~!@#;%^*()+={}|<>"', and space. " / " can only use as the tenant separator
 [error code 541: internal error]
    at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ConnectionCloseMethodHandler.methodReceived(ConnectionCloseMethodHandler.java:91)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.dispatchConnectionClose(ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.java:192)
    at org.wso2.andes.framing.amqp_0_91.ConnectionCloseBodyImpl.execute(ConnectionCloseBodyImpl.java:140)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.state.AMQStateManager.methodReceived(AMQStateManager.java:111)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.methodBodyReceived(AMQProtocolHandler.java:517)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolSession.methodFrameReceived(AMQProtocolSession.java:467)
    at org.wso2.andes.framing.AMQMethodBodyImpl.handle(AMQMethodBodyImpl.java:96)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler$2.run(AMQProtocolHandler.java:468)
    at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.processAll(Job.java:109)
    at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.run(Job.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more

2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: training.csv 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: DueTopic1 - Node 1- Sub 1 1-1 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: DueTopic1 - Node 1- Sub 1 1-1 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: training.csv 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory: InitialContextFactory.close() called and Context instances cleaned up 
2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Comment: Where did you place CSV Data Set Config?

Comment: As shown in the first image csv file is in the home directory. The CSV file is accessible because I published a message with the body been set by the same CSV file

Comment: Yes, but in your Test Plan, where did you put the component?

Comment: I have added CSV data set config under the test plan as the first item which is then followed by the thread group

Comment: Insert it into the thread group...

Comment: I already tried that but the same result

Comment: Could you share the jmeter log?

Comment: Did your CSV file locates in the `jmeter/bin` directory?

Comment: Still it fails to read even after I added the csv data set config inside the thread group. @Adnan attached the log file and I have tried executing it inside bin as well as from a separate folder the result is same.

Comment: Try once run the test leaving the `Delimiter` field blank in the `CSV Dataset Config` settings.

Comment: or double check that you don't have any `space` at the end of the line in the `training.csv` file.

Comment: @Adnan checked with delimeter blank and also double checked for spaces. Still it does not allow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the csv dataset config is placed in correct place. Ideally under the thread group.

Also if it's failing to read the value from csv file, you should see some error logged in jmeter.log file or if you enable logs on JMeter UI. If it says something related to csv file, that will help you debug further. Normally keep the csv file in same folder where your jmx resides and just mention the filename.csv in CSV dataset config.

Comment: Tried out by placing the csv placed within the thread group and still the same result. I have attached the question with the JMeter log.

Comment: I don't see CSV file being loaded in the log. Can you try adding your csv dataset config as child of JMS sampler?

Comment: The csv file is loaded - 2016/08/29 17:56:39 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: training.csv